# DateTime.ToUniversalTime applying -1 hour for October but not for November

Tags: c#, date, datetime, localization, datetimeoffset

If you run:
`(new DateTime(2021, 11, 01)).ToUniversalTime()`
The result is: [01/11/2021 00:00:00]
But if you run:
`(new DateTime(2021, 10, 01)).ToUniversalTime()`
There result is: [30/09/2021 23:00:00]

What gives?

Comment: What country/locale are you running that in? Chances are you switch away from daylight savings sometime between the 1st October and 1st November

Comment: The majority of time zones (nothern hemisphere) switch back from Daylight Savings Time during October

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. Would you mind putting it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified what time zone you're in, but it's likely that it's somewhere which has Daylight Savings Time over the summer period, which ends somewhere between 2021/10/01 and 2021/11/01.

For example, in Bulgaria (which your profile says you're from), daylight savings ends on 2021/10/31.